# Is there any difference betwen [=] and [&] in lambda functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was studying lambda function in c++11 recently. But I don't know if there is any difference between `[=]` and `[&]`. If there is, what the difference is?

And in these two situation, does `this` in lambda body has any difference?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The difference is how the values are captured

- `&` captures by reference
- `=` captures by value

Quick example

```
int x = 1;
auto valueLambda = [=]() { cout << x << endl; };
auto refLambda = [&]() { cout << x << endl; };
x = 13;
valueLambda();
refLambda();
```

This code will print

```
1
13
```

The first lambda captures `x` by value at the point in which `valueLambda` is defined.  Hence it gets the current value of `1`.  But the `refLambda` captures a reference to the local so it sees the up to date value

Comment: Thank you. And what about my second question? If the lambda function is in a class, does `this` in lambda body has any difference?

Comment: @pktangyue it doesn't affect the capture of `this` because `this` is always captured by value

Comment: @JaredPar I don't get it why valueLambda() prints 1 despite it captures by value, value of x is changed to 13 before a call is made to valueLambda?

Comment: @gaurav valueLambda() captures the value of x at the time valueLambda() is defined, not when it is called. x = 13; is after the definition of valueLambda().

Answer (score 15):

- & means "capture by reference".
- = means "capture by value".

I replied here because I want to point out one thing:

`this` pointer is always captured by value. In C++11, this means, that if you want to capture a copy of a variable in a class, such as `this->a`, it will always be captured by reference in practice. Why?

Consider:

```
[this]() { ++this->a; }
```

`this` is captured by value, but this is a pointer, so a is referenced through `this`.

If you want a copy of a member variable, in C++11, do something like this:

```
auto copy = this->a;
[copy]() mutable { ++copy; }
```

Beware of this caveat, because it is not intuitive until you think of it.

Comment: Also, if you are going to modify the copy inside the lambda you must specify it as mutable: [copy]() mutable { ++copy; }

Answer (score 0):

The first question JaredPar already answered.

For your second quesiton, the this in lambda body is same as the this of its containing class. The following example is from standard.

```
struct S1 {
  int x, y;
  int operator()(int);
  void f() {
    [=]()->int {
      return operator()(this->x + y); 
      // equivalent to S1::operator()(this->x + (*this).y)
      // this has type S1*
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[=] by using this it will not  change the  real value it's limit will be inside  this scope .

[&] by using this section u can take the reference any variable in it and whatever the changes happen inside this lamba fucn the actual value of the variable also changes

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that is not already there in the old answers.